# Passing className prop to Material-ui child/inner elements

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to assign a css class to the inner elements of a Material-UI component. Using the `<RaisedButton />` component as an example, lets say that I want to apply a className to the label element within Raised Button.

`<RaisedButton labelStyle={{...}}`.

Since `labelStyle` is looking for an object, how would I apply a custom css class rather than adding inline code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the other answer, but you can pass a `<span>` element as the `label` property rather than as a child:

```
<RaisedButton label={<span className="your-class">Your label</span>} />
```

This preserves the inline style/theme applied by `RaisedButton`.

https://jsfiddle.net/L8d2b1y7/1/

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Your answer reminded me that I did just that in the AppBar component with the iconElementLeft/Right props in another file a long time ago. I guess my brain just refused to provide that connection in a different context.

Answer (score 2):

Think you can pass the label as a child rather than in the props.

```html
<RaisedButton>
  <span className="your-class">Your label</span>
</RaisedButton>
```

The className prop for RaisedButton only applies to the root element.

Comment: While viable, one would then have none of the label styles that material-ui offers. I suppose I should have been more specific that I want to be able to keep those styles while adding/overriding styles with a class rather than inline. 

In regards to the last line, you're saying there's no way to pass that prop to the child elements?

Comment: Tom's answer is correct, but you can also use the label property... <RaisedButton label={<span className="your-class">Your label</span>} /> ...if you want to take advantage of the theming/styling applied by RaisedButton (for example, the "font-size" and "text-transform" that it applies) before your css class is applied.  You may in fact NOT want those build in styles applied with your css class - if not, put span as child as Tom suggests.